# How do I re-route header menu items to a URL instead of internal file in React/Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I'm modifying a react Gatsby template and can't figure out how to re-route a header menu item to link to an external URL while keeping the rest of the menu items the same. The Header file contains the following nested files:
`Header.js`
`Index.js`
`menuItems.js`

The behavior is governed in the `Header.js` file like this:

```
import { menuItems } from "./menuItems";

<Menu
  className="navbar-nav d-none d-lg-flex"
  dark={isDark ? 1 : 0}
>
  {menuItems.map(
    (
      { label, isExternal = false, name, items, ...rest },
      index
    ) => {
      const hasSubItems = Array.isArray(items);
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={name + index}>
          {hasSubItems ? (
            <li className="nav-item dropdown" {...rest}>
              <a
                className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                role="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
                href="/#"
                onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
              >
                {label}
              </a>
              <MenuDropdown
                className="menu-dropdown dropdown-right"
                dark={isDark ? 1 : 0}
              >
                {items.map((subItem, indexSub) => {
                  const hasInnerSubItems = Array.isArray(
                    subItem.items
                  );
                  return (
                    <React.Fragment
                      key={subItem.name + indexSub}
                    >
                      {hasInnerSubItems ? (
                        <li className="drop-menu-item dropdown">
                          <a
                            className="dropdown-toggle"
                            role="button"
                            data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            href="/#"
                            onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                          >
                            {subItem.label}
                          </a>
                          <MenuDropdown
                            className="menu-dropdown dropdown-right"
                            dark={isDark ? 1 : 0}
                          >
                            {subItem.items.map(
                              (itemInner, indexInnerMost) => (
                                <li
                                  className="drop-menu-item"
                                  key={
                                    itemInner.name +
                                    indexInnerMost
                                  }
                                >
                                  {itemInner.isExternal ? (
                                    <a
                                      href={`${itemInner.name}`}
                                      target="_blank"
                                      rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                    >
                                      {itemInner.label}
                                    </a>
                                  ) : (
                                    <Link
                                      to={`/${itemInner.name}`}
                                    >
                                      {itemInner.label}
                                    </Link>
                                  )}
                                </li>
                              )
                            )}
                          </MenuDropdown>
                        </li>
                      ) : (
                        <li className="drop-menu-item">
                          {subItem.isExternal ? (
                            <a
                              href={`${subItem.name}`}
                              target="_blank"
                              rel="noopener noreferrer"
                            >
                              {subItem.label}
                            </a>
                          ) : (
                            <Link to={`/${subItem.name}`}>
                              {subItem.label}
                            </Link>
                          )}
                        </li>
                      )}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  );
                })}
              </MenuDropdown>
            </li>
          ) : (
            <li className="nav-item" {...rest}>
              {isExternal ? (
                <a
                  className="nav-link"
                  href={`${name}`}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                  {label}
                </a>
              ) : (
                <Link
                  className="nav-link"
                  to={`/${name}`}
                  role="button"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                >
                  {label}
                </Link>
              )}
            </li>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  )}
</Menu>
```

The `menuItems.js` file is setup like this:

```
export const menuItems = [
  {
    name: "product",
    label: "Product",
  },
  {
    name: "solutions",
    label: "Solutions",
  },
  {
    name: "company",
    label: "Company",
  },
  {
    name: "support",
    label: "Support",
  },
  {
    name: "sign-in",
    label: "Sign In",
  },
];
```

I want to make `name: "sign-in"` route to an external https URL, but I want the rest to stay the same (which means they simply link to a page...`support.js` for example.

1. I'm not sure how to do this
2. It seemed like I was close a couple times, but `react` is inserting a leading `/` in front of the URL

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: if can display sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) .it's great.

Answer (score 1):

`Header.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { menuItems } from "./menuItems";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
export default function Header() {
  return (
    <div>
      {menuItems.map((menuItem) => (
        <li className="nav-item" key={menuItem.name}>
          {menuItem.isExternal ? (
            <a
              className="nav-link"
              href={`${menuItem.name}`}
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              {menuItem.label}
            </a>
          ) : (
            <Link
              className="nav-link"
              to={`/${menuItem.name}`}
              role="button"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              {menuItem.label}
            </Link>
          )}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`menuItems.js`

```
export const menuItems = [
  {
    name: "product",
    label: "Product",
    isExternal: false,
  },
  {
    name: "solutions",
    label: "Solutions",
    isExternal: false,
  },
  {
    name: "company",
    label: "Company",
    isExternal: false,
  },
  {
    name: "support",
    label: "Support",
    isExternal: false,
  },
  {
    name: "sign-in",
    label: "Sign In",
    isExternal: true,
  },
];
```

You have to modify the `menuItem` array slightly, add the `isExternal:true or false`. Then you can loop over this array to create your dynamic links in  `Header.js`.

Comment: Thanks!! Where should I insert the URL I'd like for `sign-in` to point to?

Comment: In your ```menuItems ``` array. Example ```{name: "https://www.google.co.in/",label: "Sign In",isExternal: true,}```

Comment: Cool, makes sense. Although I'm seeing now that I should have provided the full code for `Header.js`. I.m going to modify it above. Any updated suggestions would be amazing!

Comment: Looking at your updated Header.js file its more complex(also have some issues i believe). It will not be possible for me or anyone in stack overflow to answer with out a clear question/problem. If you can upload your project in codesandbox.io and share i'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time. I'll have a member of my team take a look. I was trying to learn this myself to upskill. I'll reach back out if needed. Thanks again!!!